# How to make header of my chat container be scrollable for every element in it and not overlap

Tags: html, css

My goal here is to make the header of this chatbox be scrollable when the number of elements exceeds the maximum width. I have currently tried to apply the word wrap (no wrap) however that doesn't work and positioning it to absolute seems to break my chats interface and still doesn't work. I need it to be scrollable instead of breaking onto new lines. How do I do this?
HTML Code:

```css
.chatHeader {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.chatHeaderItem {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.20s linear;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.chatHeaderItem:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chatContainer {
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
}

.chatWindow {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 8px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.chatFooter {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
}

.chatFooterLabel {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  font-size: 14px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  float: right;
  transition: all 0.20s linear;
}

.chatFooterLabel:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.3);
}

.chatInputField {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  width: calc(75% - 20px);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  transition: all 0.20s linear;
}

.chatMessage {
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.chatTime {
  color: rgba(250, 250, 230, 0.4);
  font-size: 10px;
}

.chatUser {
  color: #747474;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 7px black, 0 0 5px black;
}

.chatXbox {
  color: #00FF74;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 7px black, 0 0 5px #4cff9d;
}

.chatPlaystation {
  color: #4285f4;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 7px black, 0 0 5px #7aa9f7;
}

.chatPC {
  color: #6441a4;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 7px black, 0 0 5px #927abf;
}

.chatMod {
  color: #FFD700;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 7px #ffdb19, 0 0 5px #ffe34c;
}

.chatAdmin {
  color: #ff5719;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 7px orange, 0 0 5px darkorange;
}

.chatRoles {
  font-size: 10px;
  background: black;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatContainer" id="chatContainer">
  <div class="chatHeader">
    <div class="chatHeaderItem">Global</div>
    <div class="chatHeaderItem">xExemplaryx</div>
    <div class="chatHeaderItem">Ninja</div>
    <div class="chatHeaderItem">NotTfue</div>
    <div class="chatHeaderItem">Myth</div>
    <div class="chatHeaderItem">Global</div>
    <div class="chatHeaderItem">xExemplaryx</div>
    <div class="chatHeaderItem">Ninja</div>
    <div class="chatHeaderItem">NotTfue</div>
    <div class="chatHeaderItem">Myth</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chatWindow">
    <div class="chatMessage"><span class="chatTime">[2:41 AM] </span><span class="chatPlaystation">SaltyyPP</span>: anyone wanna do some duo scrims NAE?</div>
    <div class="chatMessage"><span class="chatTime">[2:44 AM] </span><span class="chatXbox">Nexus</span>: anyone wanna do sms NAE?</div>
    <div class="chatMessage"><span class="chatTime">[2:41 AM] </span><span class="chatPC">Dusty</span>: anyone wanna do some duo scrims NAE?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chatFooter">
    <input type="text" class="chatInputField" />
    <div class="chatFooterLabel">Send</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chatRoles">
    Roles: <span class="chatAdmin">Admin</span>, <span class="chatMod">Moderator</span>, <span class="chatPlaystation">Playstation</span>, <span class="chatPC">PC</span>, <span class="chatXbox">Xbox</span>, <span class="chatUser">User</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Live JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sjac7du9/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex` for the parent container and add `overflow-x:scroll`

```
.chatHeader {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    display:flex;
}
```

By default the direction of flex is horizontal.